# javascript pushing object to the array at for loop changes the front components

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to push different objects at each time, but it changes the front components while looping the for loop. Here is my code.

```
let responseArray = [];

const sendBatchRequest = async function (response) {
    try {
        console.log(`response: ${JSON.stringify(response)}`);
        if (responseArray.length < 9) {
            responseArray.push(response); // push 9 components
            console.log(`responseArray at if: ${JSON.stringify(responseArray)}`);
        } else {
            responseArray.push(response); // push last 10th component
            console.log(`responseArray at else: ${JSON.stringify(responseArray)}`);
            for (let i = 0; i < responseArray.length; i++) {
                console.log(`responseArray ${i} - ${JSON.stringify(responseArray[i])}`);
            }
            // do something...
            responseArray = []; // reset the array
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(`sendBatchRequest err: ${err}`);
    }
}

const main = async function () {
    try {
        const result = {};
        for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            result.data = i;
            await sendBatchRequest(result);
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(`main err: ${err}`);
    }
}

main();
```

And my result looks like this.

```
response: {"data":0}
responseArray at if: [{"data":0}]
response: {"data":1}
responseArray at if: [{"data":1},{"data":1}]
response: {"data":2}
responseArray at if: [{"data":2},{"data":2},{"data":2}]
response: {"data":3}
responseArray at if: [{"data":3},{"data":3},{"data":3},{"data":3}]
response: {"data":4}
responseArray at if: [{"data":4},{"data":4},{"data":4},{"data":4},{"data":4}]
```

I can't understand why at 2th loop, `responseArray[0]` changes `{"data":0}` to `{"data":1}`. I want my `responseArray` looks like `[{"data":0},{"data":1"},...]`. What's happening on `Array.push(object)` at javascript? And how could I get the result what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're passing the result variable as a reference, everytime the result.data changes, so as the pushed items on the `responseArray` will be changed also.

So to avoid that. do this instead:

```js
let responseArray = [];

const sendBatchRequest = async function (response) {
    try {
        console.log(`response: ${JSON.stringify(response)}`);
        if (responseArray.length < 9) {
            responseArray.push(response); // push 9 components
            console.log(`responseArray at if: ${JSON.stringify(responseArray)}`);
        } else {
            responseArray.push(response); // push last 10th component
            console.log(`responseArray at else: ${JSON.stringify(responseArray)}`);
            for (let i = 0; i < responseArray.length; i++) {
                console.log(`responseArray ${i} - ${JSON.stringify(responseArray[i])}`);
            }
            // do something...
            responseArray = []; // reset the array
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(`sendBatchRequest err: ${err}`);
    }
}

const main = async function () {
    try {
        for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            const result = {data: i};  // Do this change
            await sendBatchRequest(result);
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(`main err: ${err}`);
    }
}

main();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are pushing the same object reference (not a copy) each time into the array. So every iteration of the for loop modifies that object

Change:

```
    const result = {};
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        result.data = i;
        await sendBatchRequest(result);
    }
```

To

```
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        // new object each iteration
        const result = {data : i};            
        await sendBatchRequest(result);
    }
```